# Customising UITabBarItems in their controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In previous applications I have customised my tabBarItems by overriding init (see below)

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [self tabBarItem];
        [tabBarItem setTitle:@"ONE"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

After looking at the Xcode templates I am now thinking that I would be better to add this customisation to initWithNibName:bundle: instead.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [self tabBarItem];
        [tabBarItem setTitle:@"ONE"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

does this make sense, it seems like it does to me, but I just wanted to check?

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you load your controller from a Nib (xib) file or not (and so you do all the work programmatically in the init) I guess

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, much appreciate, I just wanted to get a 2nd opinion to make sure I was on the right track.